# Significado de error “connection reset by peer” en conexión TCP

Tags: tcpip, tcp

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación cliente-servidor los cuales se comunican sobre el protocolo TCP/IP, donde esporádicamente obtengo el error `connection reset by peer`.

Por "connection  **reset**" entiendo que la conexión ¿se ha reiniciado? o ¿esto significa que el sistema cliente se ha desconectado del servidor y la no es posible la comunicación entre ambos?

Comment: Posible pregunta duplicada de : [What does “connection reset by peer” mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434451/what-does-connection-reset-by-peer-mean)

Comment: mi pregunta es diferente en:  _¿se ha reiniciado? o ¿Esto significa que el sistema cliente se ha desconectado del servidor y la no es posible la comunicación entre ambos?_, además este es el stack en español no el original en ingles.

Comment: @ratlab no es duplicada ya que esta es otra comunidad, y el link que propones es de stackoverflow en ingles.

Comment: Significa que se genero un error de red cuando el cliente estaba recibiendo los datos del servidor. Podríamos decir que el servidor esta aceptando la conexión, enseguida procesa la solicitud y finalmente envía la respuesta al cliente. Sin embargo, cuando el servidor cierra el socket, el cliente piensa que la conexión se ha terminado de manera anormal ya que la implementación del socket envía un segmento de restablecimiento de TCP, que le dice al cliente que deseche los datos e informe un error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Significa que el otro lado<sup>*</sup> de la conexión lo terminó.

Si el servidor recibió este error, quiere decir que el cliente terminó la conexión.  Si es el cliente que lo recibió, quiere decir que el servidor la terminó.

*Digo "el otro lado de la conexión", pero es importante recordar que eso es *sólo* desde el punto de vista del lado que recibió el error. Es posible que un firewall, router, o otra máquina entre los dos puntos finales, de hecho, terminó la conexión. Y a veces, es posible que los *dos* puntos finales pueden recibir el mismo error.

Answer (score 0):

Significa que el servidor te ha enviado un flag `RST` (Reset) para terminar la conexión, es decir, el servidor está abortando la conexión porque ha sido rechazada tal vez debido a que la conexión está parcialmente formada.

Es similar al flag `FIN` (Finish), pero este se envía como finalización en una conexión exitosa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No significa que **el servidor**, específicamente, te ha enviado un RST... sino que **tu par** lo ha hecho. El concepto de servidor y cliente no existe en IP.

Comment: Concuerdo con @Flimzy, además me parece que la ilustración que aportas no es tan clara, pero gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @Flimzy solo estoy asumiendo, ya que es un aplicación cliente/servidor como menciona Hector en su pregunta, que el servidor al cual se está conectando ha enviado un RST ya que si lo estuviera haciendo deliberadamente desde el cliente entonces no tendría sentido la pregunta

Comment: Yo sé, y por eso no te di un voto negativo... Pero siempre es mejor ser lo más especifico y correcto posible. Por eso te di la sugerencia. Puedes ignorarla si quieras.